# R - Set values by group based on a condition in a dataframe

Tags: r, datatable, data-wrangling

I have the following dataset.

| group | value | row_name | overlaps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group_a | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| group_a | 5 | 2 | 3, 5 |
| group_a | 48 | 3 | 4, 5 |
| group_a | 54 | 4 | 5 |
| group_a | 12 | 5 |  |
| group_b | 12 | 6 | 7 |
| group_b | 1 | 7 |  |

The overlaps column indicates which rows have a certain 'overlap'.

I would like, *only for rows whose value is greater than 10*, to replace the data in the value column with zero for all rows indicated in the respective 'overlaps' column.

Expected output:

| group | value | row_name | overlaps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group_a | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| group_a | 5 | 2 | 3, 5 |
| group_a | 48 | 3 | 4, 5 |
| group_a | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| group_a | 0 | 5 |  |
| group_b | 12 | 6 | 7 |
| group_b | 0 | 7 |  |

Reproducible example:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("group_a", "group_a", "group_a", "group_a",
                             "group_a", "group_b", "group_b"),
                   value = c(4, 5 , 48, 54, 12, 12, 1),
                   row_name = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
                   overlaps = c("2", "3, 5", "4, 5", "5", "", "7", ""))
```

I don't know if it's a very complex issue, but I'm stuck for hours and I didn't figure out how to solve it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can solve this, by group, using dplyr or data.table?

Comment: I don't follow the logic. Why is the third row not 0 too? It's > 10 and it's in one of the overlap lists.

Comment: @thelatemail The third line is in the overlap list of second line.  The value of row 2 is not greater than 10. For this reason, the value of row 3 does not become 0. Unlike rows 4 and 5, which are in the overlap list of a row 3 whose value is > 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsplit` the `overlaps` column, subset to just those where `data$value  > 10`, then use that distinct set of `row_name`s to overwrite the original data with `0`:

```
gr10 <- data$value > 10
sel <- Map(paste, data$group[gr10], strsplit(data$overlaps, ",\\s+")[gr10], sep="|")
sel <- Reduce(union, sel)
sel
#[1] "group_a|4" "group_a|5" "group_a|"  "group_b|7"
data$value[do.call(paste, c(data[c("group","row_name")], sep="|")) %in% sel] <- 0
data
#    group value row_name overlaps
#1 group_a     4        1        2
#2 group_a     5        2     3, 5
#3 group_a    48        3     4, 5
#4 group_a     0        4        5
#5 group_a     0        5         
#6 group_b    12        6        7
#7 group_b     0        7
```

If the `row_name`s are unique across the entire dataset, you can use simpler logic:

```
sel <- Reduce(union, strsplit(data$overlaps, ",\\s+")[data$value > 10])
sel
#[1] "4" "5" "7"
data$value[data$row_name %in% sel] <- 0
```

Bonus *data.table* solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[
  data[value > 10, .(row_name=unlist(strsplit(overlaps, ",\\s+"))), by=group],
  on=.(group, row_name),
  value := 0
]
```

Comment: do you know if there any way that this logic can be applied by groups instead of considering the 'dataframe as a whole'?

Comment: Certainly. If you can show an example of how 2 groups look, I can update the answer.

Comment: @Quizicall - see the update

Comment: Just to note, if the rownames are unique, even across groups, the original logic would have worked too. I didn't want to assume this however.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, based on `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(group = c("group_a", "group_a", "group_a", "group_a",
                             "group_a", "group_b", "group_b"),
                   value = c(4, 5 , 48, 54, 12, 12, 1),
                   row_name = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
                   overlaps = c("2", "3, 5", "4, 5", "5", "", "7", ""))

data %>% 
  separate(
    overlaps, into=c("o1", "o2"), sep=", ", fill="right", remove=F) %>% 
  mutate(across(o1:o2, ~ ifelse(value > 10, get(cur_column()), 0)),
         value = ifelse(row_number() %in% c_across(o1:o2), 0, value)) %>% 
  select(-o1, -o2)

#>     group value row_name overlaps
#> 1 group_a     4        1        2
#> 2 group_a     5        2     3, 5
#> 3 group_a    48        3     4, 5
#> 4 group_a     0        4        5
#> 5 group_a     0        5         
#> 6 group_b    12        6        7
#> 7 group_b     0        7
```